# NSIS support for Linux and Solaris

Tags: linux, solaris, nsis

Does NSIS support Linux and Solaris? I read somewhere that we can compile nsis script on Linux but cant execute the .exe generated on any other platforms but Windows. Can somebody put more light in this?

Answer (score 15):

### No.

See the [NSIS feature list](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Features)  for more information ...

> **Portable Compiler**
>
> The NSIS compiler can be compiled for POSIX platforms like
>   Linux and *BSD. Generated installer
>   will still run on Windows only, but
>   this way they can be generated without
>   Windows or WINE.

Answer (score 8):

You can compile installers on POSIX and Windows systems, but it always produces a Win32 PE file that only runs on Windows (And maybe under WINE on *nix)

Check the [NSIS manual](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/AppendixG.html#G) for more info

Answer (score 5):

The installer systems for Windows and Linux are completely different.

Whereas Windows' only contribution to a software management system is one registry entry pointing to the uninstaller, Linux has a full working software management system. There are apt, yum, pacman and many more out there, which are supporting many more features and possibilities including automatic execution of scripts and pulling in/installing dependencies. If you have a cross platform application you wanna share, you're either stuck with creating a tar-ball, or you learn how to build deb/rpm etc. packages.

Comment: Actually Windows does have a software management system, MSI, but is of an entirely different beast than Linux's, it's a nightmare, and that's why NSIS doesn't use it :)

Answer (score 0):

Linux and Windows are not binary compatible, so you can't do that.

But, most of the windows binary installer could able to install at [WINE](http://www.winehq.org/)